# OSX - Catch to print jobs.

Tags: c, macos, printing

I've been doing my research but I can't find a way of catching how many print jobs a user has sent to the printer (or how many pages have printed).

What I want to do is a simple counter of pages printed by a OSX user. Have you seen anything like it?

1.- Be able to count how many print jobs via software in the computer, not the printer.
2.- Counting how many pages?

Answer (score 0):

OS X uses cups for printing. You can list completed jobs for user user_name with:

```
lpstat -W completed -u user_name
```

You may try to get the number of pages printed from /var/log/cups/page_log, but the content of this file depends on the printer driver. From [cups documentation](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.6/accounting.html):

> Page Logging
>
> CUPS logs every page that is printed on a system to the page_log file.
>   Page logging is only available for drivers that provide page
>   accounting information, typically all PostScript and CUPS raster
>   devices. Raw queues and queues using third-party solutions such as
>   Foomatic generally do not have useful page accounting information
>   available.