# How can I determine the Printer Total Page Count on Mac?

Tags: macos, printing, count

I want to know how many pages I have printed using my mac and Brother HL-1110 printer. [Something like this](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c00382376) but on a Mac.

Is there a way to do that?

I have fount [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170444/osx-catch-to-print-jobs) that involves *lpstat* and shows the printed jobs but not the total count. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the printer is on, press the power button 3 times continues. you will get the printer status page. Note the total page count while replacing new toner. When that toner is finished, again take the printer settings page.  You will get the actual pages printed by the replaced catridge by subtracting the old count from the new count.